# Setting patch number through slider

Tags: netlogo

How to generate food sources through slider in ants model, like if we set 3 through slider we can see 3 food sources, in net logo.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
globals [n-food-types n-food-patches]
patches-own [food-type]

to setup
  ca
  set n-food-types 3  ;move into  slider
  let _food-types n-values n-food-types [? + 1]
  ask patches [
    set food-type 0 ;default: no food
  ]
  set n-food-patches (count patches / 2)
  ask n-of n-food-patches patches [
    set food-type one-of _food-types
  ]
  color-patches
end

to color-patches
  ask patches [
    set pcolor (5 + 10 * food-type)
  ]
end
```